# is it necessary to add my custom scala library dependencies in new scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala and I am trying to develop a small project which uses a custom library. I have created a mysql connection pool inside the library. Here's my **build.sbt** for library

```
organization := "com.learn"
name := "liblearn-scala"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" %  "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-dbcp" % "8.5.0"
```

I have published the same to local ivy repo using `sbt publishLocal`

Now I have a project which will be making use of the above library with following **build.sbt**

```
name := "SBT1"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.learn" % "liblearn-scala_2.12" % "0.1"
```

I am able to compile the new project but when I run it I get

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

But if I add

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" %  "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-dbcp" % "8.5.0"
```

in the project's build.sbt it works without any issues.

**Is this the actual way of doing things with scala - sbt? ie : I have to mention dependencies of custom library also inside the project?**

Here is my library code (I have just 1 file)

```
package com.learn.scala.db
import java.sql.Connection
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2._

object MyMySQL {

  private val dbUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school?autoReconnect=true"
  private val connectionPool = new BasicDataSource()

  connectionPool.setUsername("root")
  connectionPool.setPassword("xyz")

  connectionPool.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
  connectionPool.setUrl(dbUrl)
  connectionPool.setInitialSize(3)

  def getConnection: Connection = connectionPool.getConnection

}
```

This is my project code:

```
  try {
    val conn = MyMySQL.getConnection
    val ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from school")
    val rs = ps.executeQuery()

    while (rs.next()) {
      print(rs.getString("name"))
      print(rs.getString("rank"))
      println("----------------------------------")
    }

    rs.close()
    ps.close()
    conn.close()

  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      println(ex.printStackTrace())
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SBT fetches all project dependencies, transitively. This means it should be necessary to explicitly declare only `liblearn-scala`, and not also the transitive dependencies `mysql-connector-java` and `tomcat-dbcp`. Transitivity can be [disabled](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Disable+Transitivity), and transitive dependencies can be [excluded](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies), however unless this has been done explicitly, then it should not be the cause of the problem.

Without seeing your whole `build.sbt`, I believe you are doing the right thing. If `sbt clean publishLocal` is not solving the problem, you could try the nuclear option and clear the whole ivy cache (note this will force all projects to re-fetch dependencies).

Comment: Thank you!, I had to clear the whole ivy cache and it worked